# CorePlot - Annotations swinging in the Scatter Plot

Tags: ios, swift, graph, annotations, core-plot

In my app I've a CorePlot which hosts three scatterplots, I've also configured as follows,

```
    let borderStyle       = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    borderStyle.lineColor = maxPlotColor

    let textLayer             = CPTTextLayer(text: "MAX")
    textLayer.fill            = CPTFill(color: .white())
    textLayer.cornerRadius    = 10.0
    textLayer.borderLineStyle = borderStyle

    maxLabelAnnotation              = CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation(plotSpace: maxLinePlot.plotSpace!, anchorPlotPoint: [5, NSNumber(value: kMaxLineValue)])
    maxLabelAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer

    maxLinePlot.graph?.plotAreaFrame?.plotArea?.addAnnotation(maxLabelAnnotation)
```

The annotations are updated dynamically when the plot data is updated. The code snippet is shown below,

```
func newData(_ theTimer: Timer) {
    // MARK: Dynmic annotations
    maxLabelAnnotation.anchorPlotPoint  = [NSNumber(value: currentIndex - 18), NSNumber(value: kMaxLineValue)]
    riskLabelAnnotation.anchorPlotPoint = [NSNumber(value: currentIndex - 18), NSNumber(value: kRiskLineValue)] }
```

The problem is shown in the figure, where the annotation is moving back and froth as the graph moving continuously 
[image: graph with annotation swinging]

I just want to stick the annotation in a position with out any swinging. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The annotations are locked to the plot space as it scrolls, but you update their anchor positions with each new data point, causing them to jump to the next position. Use layer annotations instead of plot space annotations to lock them in place. You'll need to recalculate the y-positions if the scale of the y-axis changes but the labels will stay in place as the graph scrolls below them.

Do this after the view hierarchy is build and everything is laid out so the view calculations are correct.

```
maxLinePlot.layoutIfNeeded()

if let plotArea = maxLinePlot.graph?.plotAreaFrame?.plotArea {
    let plotSpace = maxLinePlot.plotSpace!
    let viewPoint = plotSpace.plotAreaViewPoint(forPlotPoint: [0.0, kMaxLineValue])

    let maxLabelAnnotation          = CPTLayerAnnotation(anchorLayer: plotArea)
    maxLabelAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer
    maxLabelAnnotation.xConstraints = CPTConstraints(relativeOffset: 0.25)
    maxLabelAnnotation.yConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: viewPoint.y)

    plotArea.addAnnotation(maxLabelAnnotation)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric you're the God of CorePlot! Could you please give any code snippets as I've lost the clue here!

Comment: now as I've tried your code getting "Value of type 'CPTLayerAnnotation' has no member 'xConstraints'" this error.

Comment: You need to use the code on the `release-2.3` branch. The constraints properties were added after the 2.2 release.